# How do I dynamically load HTML into a Winforms WebViewControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, microsoft-edge

The Visual Studio [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) component uses the Microsoft Edge browser and is the upgraded version of the WebBrowser control that used older Internet Explorer technology, but the API is different.

Does anyone know the equivalent **WebView** control call for:

`WebBrowser.DocumentText = "<html>Dynamic page content</html>`";

Comment: I only see a `Source` property so you might have to save that html to a file and use a URI.

Comment: Try `WebView.NavigateToString("<html>Dynamic page content</html>")`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the suggestion given by the @aepot that you can use the WebView.NavigateToString to load the dynamic HTML.

```
webView2.NavigateToString("<html> Test code </html>");
```

If it is a file then you can do like this:

```
 webView2.NavigateToString(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/11.html"));
```

OR

```
webView2.NavigateToLocal(@"\12.html");
```